# Continuous function in terms of cover.

Tags: general-topology

I missed todays lecture and while going through the lecture script I cam across a theorem I need some light on.

> Let $f:X \to Y$ be a map and $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ an open or finite and closed cover. Then $f$ continuous iff $f_i = f|_{A_i}$ continuous $\forall i \in I$

This is what I think the theorem should say, can anyone validate? Also what does $f|_{A_i}$ mean? Is it $f_i=f|_{A_i} : A_i \to Y$?

Comment: It's indeed true. Instead of a closed and finite cover, we can also use a closed and locally finite cover, in fact. Each $A_i$ has the subspace topology from $X$,a nd so continuityof the restriction $f_i$ is considered as continuity between that subspace topology and the topology on $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the restriction to $A_i$ of $f$. The crucial fact here is that $(f|A_i)^{-1}[B] = f^{-1}[B] \cap A_i$